# Facebook GraphAPI to retrieve all user profile images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve all user profile images by user id and access token using Facebook Graph API.

I can take all user's albums in this way: {user-id}/albums?fields=type

In this list I can see an album with type = profile.

Is possible to change my request to filter directly this album?

Are there an others methods to take all user's profile images (for example using a single FB request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t filter, you have to get all albums and browse through them in your code to find the profile album. After that, you just need to make another API call to `/{album-id}/photos` to get access to the photos.